# BulkActionButtons and Filters

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How to show/hide `BulkActionButtons` depending on an active filter?
I'd like to show some `BulkActionButtons` when a specific filter is applied (Boolean filter) and to show other `BulkActionButtons` otherwise.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about state variables placed outside the `List` component?

1. Pass the `set()` callbacks to a custom `filters` components where you can set the state  and then
2. Pass the `state` to a custom `bulkActions` component where you can solve the conditions